# To use PPA on 12.04 LTS Cloud Image

Tags: 12.04, ppa, juju, maas

In a earlier post I had asked the question of why juju and MAAS wasn't working and outlined all of the steps.

When using the 12.04 LTS cloud image should I still need to add the PPA for juju and maas? I understand it is important to have the latest with the install. However, my concern is will this break something that would work without PPA now that 13.10 is out?

Answer (score 1):

The versions of Juju and MAAS are older and we plan on continuing to backport releases to 12.04 over it's life, however this process takes time and that's why 1.16 in Precise yet.

However I don't recommend adding the individual Juju and MAAS PPAs if you need them, instead we provide what we call the Ubuntu Cloud Archive. Since Juju/MAAS/OpenStack and all it's associated tools are usually used together we put them all in one place.

This archive is tested *as a whole* and certified by Canonical and it's what we recommend for production use of Juju and MAAS for 12.04 LTS users. This way you have the tested set of everything instead of having to worry about which PPAs to add or not.

Here's how to enable it:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/cloud-archive-instructions

Comment: When I try to 'activate' this and install MAAS, I get an internal 500 server error.

Comment: Can you file a bug and pass the link along to me? (Contact info is in my profile), thanks!